# Opening Heron UI is very slow

Tags: streaming, apache-storm, stream-processing, heron, apache-aurora

When I try to open the `http://myip:8889/topologies` after running `heron-tracker` and `heron-ui` commands, the response speed of this page is very slow even I can't open the page at all.
And the 304 response code showed as following:

```
[2018-03-20 07:08:48 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.61ms
[2018-03-20 07:08:48 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 22.92ms
[2018-03-20 07:09:37 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 19.46ms
[2018-03-20 07:09:44 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.50ms
[2018-03-20 07:09:44 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 20.93ms
[2018-03-20 07:10:35 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.59ms
[2018-03-20 07:10:35 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 21.38ms
[2018-03-20 07:12:08 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.67ms
[2018-03-20 07:12:08 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 26.07ms
[2018-03-20 07:12:51 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.49ms
[2018-03-20 07:12:51 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 19.26ms
[2018-03-20 07:13:35 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.74ms
[2018-03-20 07:13:35 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 20.34ms
[2018-03-20 07:15:25 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.59ms
[2018-03-20 07:15:26 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 22.73ms
[2018-03-20 07:18:26 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 22.43ms
[2018-03-20 07:22:17 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 24.61ms
```

When I using `heron-tracker --verbose` command to run the heron-tracker. The output as following:

```
yitian@heron04:~$ heron-tracker --verbose
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Connecting to zk hostports: [('heron04', 2181)] rootpath: /heron
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: ZK loop started
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Skipping state change
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Connecting to heron04:2181
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]:     Using session_id: None session_passwd: 00000000000000000000000000000000
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Sending request(xid=None): Connect(protocol_version=0, last_zxid_seen=0, time_out=10000, session_id=0, passwd='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', read_only=None)
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Read response Connect(protocol_version=0, last_zxid_seen=0, time_out=10000, session_id=99755698212438030, passwd='\x17H\xb5\x19E\x14:\x03\x8a\x89dX\x9a\x1cZ\xde', read_only=False)
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Session created, session_id: 99755698212438030 session_passwd: 1748b51945143a038a8964589a1c5ade
    negotiated session timeout: 10000
    connect timeout: 10000
    read timeout: 6666.66666667
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Zookeeper connection established, state: CONNECTED
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Sending request(xid=1): Exists(path='/heron/topologies', watcher=None)
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Reading for header ReplyHeader(xid=1, zxid=1596, err=0)
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Received response(xid=1): ZnodeStat(czxid=96, mzxid=96, ctime=1520689567390, mtime=1520689567390, version=0, cversion=26, aversion=0, ephemeralOwner=0, dataLength=0, numChildren=0, pzxid=1518)
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Adding children watch for path: /heron/topologies
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Sending request(xid=2): GetChildren(path='/heron/topologies', watcher=<bound method ChildrenWatch._watcher of <kazoo.recipe.watchers.ChildrenWatch object at 0x7fca72a2d9d0>>)
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Reading for header ReplyHeader(xid=2, zxid=1596, err=0)
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Received response(xid=2): []
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: State watch triggered for topologies.
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Topologies: []
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Existing topologies: []
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Tracker has started
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Running on port: 8888
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Using config file: /home/yitian/.herontools/conf/heron_tracker.yaml
[2018-03-27 04:53:41 +0000] [INFO]: Using state manager:
    type: zookeeper
    name: aurorazk
    hostport: heron04:2181
    rootpath: /heron
    tunnelhost: 127.0.0.1
[2018-03-27 04:53:44 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:53:44 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:53:47 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:53:47 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:53:50 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:53:50 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:53:53 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:53:53 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:53:56 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:53:56 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:00 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:00 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:03 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:03 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:06 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:06 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:09 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:09 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:12 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:12 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:16 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:16 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:19 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:19 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:22 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:22 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:25 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:25 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:28 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:28 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:31 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:31 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:34 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:34 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:38 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:38 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:44 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:44 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:47 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:47 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:50 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:50 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:53 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:53 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:54:57 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:54:57 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:00 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:00 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:03 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 0.47ms
[2018-03-27 04:55:03 +0000] [INFO]: 200 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 1.11ms
[2018-03-27 04:55:03 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:03 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:06 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:06 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:09 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:09 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:12 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:12 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:15 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:15 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:19 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:19 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:20 +0000] [INFO]: 200 GET /clusters (127.0.0.1) 1.13ms
[2018-03-27 04:55:22 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:22 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:25 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:25 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:28 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:28 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:31 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:31 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:35 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:35 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:38 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:38 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:41 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:44 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:44 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:47 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:47 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:50 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:50 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:54 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:54 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
[2018-03-27 04:55:57 +0000] [DEBUG]: Sending request(xid=-2): Ping()
[2018-03-27 04:55:57 +0000] [DEBUG]: Received Ping
```

`heorn-ui`:

```
yitian@heron04:~$ heron-ui
[2018-03-27 04:54:56 +0000] [INFO]: Listening at http://0.0.0.0:8889
[2018-03-27 04:54:56 +0000] [INFO]: Using tracker url: http://127.0.0.1:8888
[2018-03-27 04:54:56 +0000] [INFO]: Using base url: 
[2018-03-27 04:54:56 +0000] [INFO]: static/
[2018-03-27 04:55:20 +0000] [INFO]: 302 GET / (218.195.228.52) 1.10ms
[2018-03-27 04:55:20 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 32.23ms
[2018-03-27 04:56:18 +0000] [INFO]: 304 GET /topologies (218.195.228.52) 16.55ms
```

What's more, I can't find `LOG-FILES` of heron cluster that deployed in `Aurora`, `Zookeeper` and `Mesos`. Can you tell me it if you know it?
And I don't know what's wrong with it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This problem have been solved. The cause of the problem is that the network connection is abnormal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by checking the Internet connection is normal. Because I open the Heron UI in VM, there is something wrong with Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Wondering are you running Heron in a cluster or running in local laptop? If you are running in a cluster - are you running large topologies?

If you are running in local laptop - it should be fast. Can you do the following?

```
heron-tracker --verbose
```

and check the logs which might give a clue.

Comment: I running Heron in a cluster that consisted of three hosts. And this cluster was deployed with **Aurora**, **HDFS** and **Zookeeper**. In addition, the topology I running that is example topology in heron named WordCountTopology. And I did't modify it when I submitted the topology. I have edited the question after did **heron-tracker --verbose** command in the cluster. But I can find any problems in its output.